# How to alter package to support Lightning Knowledge and Classic Knowledge both?

Tags: lightning-knowledge

We manage a Salesforce app via a managed package which includes a Classic knowledge article type object lets say 'Comm_Article__kav' . Now that our customers are using Salesforce orgs with Lightning knowledge enabled in their environments, our app installation fails in them on the ground of  Article types are not allowed in Lightning knowledge enabled orgs. So how can we handle this situation. Snippet of error message while installing the package:

> (Comm_Article__kav) When Lightning Knowledge is enabled, you can’t add
>   an article type. Comm_Article__kav: When Lightning Knowledge is
>   enabled, you can’t add an article type.

Possible solutions I thought of:

1. Alter package to support Lightning Knowledge and Classic
   Knowledge both as few of our customers still use classic knowledge
2. Build our package to use dynamic references exclusively, and 
   dynamically determine whether org is operating in Lightning or Classic 
   Knowledge.

Are these feasible ? If yes, how?

Comment: This is a little too broad. Do you have any concrete code examples where issues arise? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_compare_classic_lightning.htm&type=5 The one way you could tell which version an org has is by checking for the presence of recordTypeId versus articleType

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I've added the problem statement here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283239/how-to-delete-article-type-in-a-managed-package-development-org for which this post could be a possible solution if feasible to implement. Also edited the question to add more information