# How to delete article type in a managed package development org?

Tags: lightning, lightning-knowledge

We publish an app which is a managed package and contains an article type object in Classic Knowledge. With Lightning Knowledge coming in picture, Lightning knowledge customer upgrades are failing due to an article type existing in our package. What are options for us to immediately avoid this situation as our customers are blocked from upgrades?

Edit: I came across this idea submitted on Salesforce board:https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CWebQAG, anyone knows of an existing workaround for this?

Comment: This one is a problem statement of the link you mentioned

Comment: Himanshi, David, glls, Derek, EazyE if this question looks like a duplicate of the ones you mentioned, would it be possible for you to help in finding solution to any of these questions? Thanks.